# Add element to layout and see this element in other activity

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I add to my layout new element for example button, but this element I want to add in code, not xml. And I start second activity and I want to use the same layout but I want to see this element which was added in previous layout. How I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are asking exactly but you can achieve that by adding button dynamically in first activity and also setting flags for the same (say `isButtonAdded = true`) and in other activity's onCreate(), check for that flag. If true, set button again dynamically..(you have to write code for adding button in both activities but you can check if to show it or not). Hope you got my point...

Comment: I get your point. I think about this solution and if I don't get any other, I think that it will be the best solution.